# Edit trees within an H2O GBM

Tags: python, h2o

I would like to do some kind of "custom GBM" with the H2O format, so it can be exported in MOJO.
In particular, I would like to edit trees (by changing the split rules and the leafs predictions).

I don't see anything providing access to the H2OGradientBoostingEstimator trees, and even less possibilities to modify them.
Do you know if it is it possible to do that ? (or would it require to basically re-write the h2o.estimators.gbm package...)

Many thanks !

Comment: AFAIK, there is no simple way to do this. You may try manually editing the MOJO/POJO files to get what you want, but never tried that. Otherwise, try modifying your data or hyperparameters to get the desired trees.